# Will my map function always run first

Tags: javascript

Will the map function always finish running before the if statement runs? I want to make sure that the elements in the array are always added up before the if statement runs. Will there ever be a time when the map function doesn't finish running before the if statement starts and so the if statement will not get the true value of the add variable?

```
var arr = [ '33.3%', '33.3%', '33.3%' ];
var add = 0;

arr.map(function(elem){
    add += parseInt(parseFloat(elem)*10000)
});

if (add <= 1001000 && add >= 999000) {
    console.log("passed!!")
}
```

Comment: Yes, the map function will always finish first, as javascript is single threaded, and all your code is synchronous

Comment: Tip: If it's a *synchronous* callback, it will **always** finish first. If it's an *asynchronous* callback, it will **always** finish later. It's not a race, there's logic to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Unless you have asynchronous requests or multi-threaded operations like WebWorkers, your code is synchronous, i.e. it is executed in strict order.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: No - it's the answer to the question.

Comment: `setTimeout` is synchronous…?! It's not multi-threaded, and it's not a "request"…

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.map of javascript is synchronous`, but if you want an `async` behaviour you can use `nodejs async module`.

NodeJS `Async` Map

```
var async = require('async');

var arr = ['1','2'];
async.map(arr, getInfo, function (e, r) {
  console.log(r);
});

function getInfo(name, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(null, name + 'new');
  }, 1000);
}
```

http://code.runnable.com/UyR-6c2DZZ4SmfSh/async-map-example-for-node-js

Comment: `async.map` is also "of javascript". If you specifically mean `Array.prototype.map`, please call it by that name.

Comment: @Bergi: I meant your comment, thanks changed.,